# How to fix "fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD" error in Contiki?

Tags: git, contiki

I entered a command line below.

> ../../contiki/examples/hello-world$ make TARGET=native savetarget

But I couldn't save the target because an error occurred.

> fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD

How to fix this error? please give me some advice.

Comment: Is `HEAD` used in the makefile? Is `hello-world` a git repository?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. HEAD is not used in the makefile, and hello-world is a git repository

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?